# How to get the amount of nodes with a specific label in a community within a network?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have been working with the unionFind streaming algorithm to visualize connected components of a database. I would like to output a table showing all the nodes of the network, along with the amount of nodes of a specific label in each node's respective community

For example- say i have a list of staff in an entire school district, and I would like to identify the amount of teachers in each staffmember's school (A school being a connected component of the entire district network)

I have tried assigning the setID (yielded by unionFind.stream) to each node, and calling multiple match statements to clarify further by node label. I also tried using a FOREACH statement without any luck.

```
CALL algo.unionFind.stream()
YIELD nodeId, setId 
MATCH(n)
SET n.setId = setId
MATCH setList = collect(setId)
WITH MATCH(n) WHERE n.setId in setList
MATCH p = (n) WHERE n._label = 'Teacher'
RETURN n.setID as component_id, count(p) as number_of_teachers;
```

I recognize the collect function may not have been employed correctly here. I hope to first assign the set id to each node n and then create a list of all set Ids called set list that I can call from. I instead get an error on the collect line.

Comment: I've never used `algo.unionFind.stream`, but the [documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-algorithms/current/procedures/) shows it needs a number of parameters.  Is your code above accurate?  ... Or are you using a different procedure?

Answer (score 0):

You did not show your data model, and your query appears to have numerous (syntactical and logical) errors. In addition, it seems that your stated use case can be solved very simply.

To save a lot of back-and-forth, I will just assume that your data model is very basic (and I will ignore all properties):

```
(:Teacher)-[:TEACHES_FOR]->(:District)
```

With the above data model, the following efficient query will return each `District` and the number of `TEACHES_FOR` relationships it has (which is the same as the number of teachers, in my data model):

```
MATCH (district:District)
RETURN district, SIZE(()-[:TEACHES_FOR]->(district)) AS number_of_teachers;
```

The `SIZE(()-[:TEACHES_FOR]->(district))` construct leverages neo4j's internal count of the number of relationships of each type associated with a node, and does not require actually accessing any relationships.